# thymeleaf Cannot aggregate on iterable containing nulls

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to use `thymeleaf aggregate` utility to find sum of salary from list as below

```
th:text="${#aggregates.sum(myList.![salary])}"
```

here `myList` is list of `MyObjct` as below

```
List<MyObject> myList;

public class MyObject{

private String name;
private double salary;
//getter setter
}
```

Everything works fine until salary is `null` on each item of list. On that case i am getting error
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot aggregate on iterable containing nulls`

How can i check if all items of list are `null` to prevent this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [collection selection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-collection-selection) first to eliminate entries with a `null` salary.

```
${#aggregates.sum(myList.?[salary != null].![salary])}
```

Collection selection creates a new list where each element satisfies the condition.  In this case, I'm creating a new list from myList where each item in the list has a non-null salary (`salary != null`).

Comment: it works. Could you please add a line or two explaining what exactly it is doing.